# Make and Display SOAP Request via PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to learn how to make a SOAP request and then post response in PHP. Here is my request code: http://pastebin.com/PBb2i0XN

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.restfulwebservices.net/ServiceContracts/2008/01">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:GetStockQuote>
<ns1:request>Goog</ns1:request>
</ns1:GetStockQuote>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

WSDL is http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a wrapper for SOAP. Check out http://php.net/soap. This should solve all your problems.

You first instantiate a SoapClient class using the following syntax.

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl");
```

You can then use the SoapClient::__getFunctions() method to determine the different functions your WSDL gives you.

```
public array SoapClient::__getFunctions ( void )
```

This client will enable you to call the soap functions from your WSDL as if they were PHP functions

For example in order to call the GetStockQuote method from your WSDL, all you have to do is the following.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl");
$client->GetStockQuote();
```

Also when you use the getFunctions method, you will get a list of all parameters each method in the WSDL expects.

Hope this was helpful. All the best.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more in your answer?